# How do i put a setstate function that is already within an async function, within a useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project, which is a django project with REACT as the frontend. For the homepage, there is a useState variable ('room_code') that is used. The setstate variable is set_room_code. So, i have an async function that fetches the room code from an api and then the idea is to use the set_room_code hook. But this is just not working. The issue is with the set_room_code as the code works if i simply remove it. I have tried to search up ideas but i am short on it. Any input would be appreciated.

```
useEffect( () => {
    let fetch_code = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/api/user-room');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('hi');
      console.log(data.room_code);
      
      console.log('bhao');
      set_room_code(data.room_code);
      
    };
     fetch_code();
     console.log(hi);

}, []);
```

I have tried using an extra useEffect hook but that doesnt work as well

Comment: I would say extract the `fetch_code` outside the `useEffect` and call it in `useEffect`. And with in the function component, make sure you are check if `roomCode` exists before you show your component.

Answer (score 0):

A few things, first its best practice to name the useState variable

```
const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState();
```

FYI.

Now as to your question--

```
useEffect( () => {
    let fetch_code = () => {
        fetch('/api/user-room').then((data) => {
            setRoomCode(data.room_code);
            console.log(data.room_code);
            return response.json();
        });      
    };
 fetch_code();
 console.log("this should show your RoomCode", roomCode)
}, [roomCode]);
```